# How to select element relative to 'this' in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="message">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="send_message" placeholder="Enter text ...">  </textarea>
      <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">OK</a>
      <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">Cancel</a>
```

I want to bind the click method to the 'div' element , and when one of the child 'a' elements is clicked do separate things. I am trying to distinguish between them using the button text, but the following is not working:

```
$(function(){

$('#message').click(function(){

if($(this + ">a").is(":contains(OK)")) {

        console.log("OK!!");
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What did you expect `this + '>a'` to do, exactly? Concatenating an object with a string is going to call `toString()` on the object, which will result in the string `'[Object object]>a'`. You might have tried [`$('> a', this)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) though.

Comment: Why do you want to bind the click event to the div? Why not just bind 2 separate click events to the A elements

Comment: Why don't you hook up event listener for each anchors?

Comment: I assume this contains div#message, so I thought  $(this + ">a") might select the child of  div#message that is an 'a'

Comment: #David Thomas. I think yourmethod is deprecated

Comment: Indeed, but I wasn't *recommending* it, just suggesting that might be what the OP was aiming for with his attempt.

Comment: @user61629 When the click event is fired on the Div, how do you intend to determine which anchor was clicked?  I think instead of binding to the div you need to bind to each anchor and then so a $(this).parent() to manipulate the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay there are two ways of doing this:

## .find(selector)

```
 if(this).find("a").is(":contains(OK)")) {

    console.log("OK!!");
```

OR

## $(selector,context)

```
 if("a",this).is(":contains(OK)")) {

    console.log("OK!!");
```

Comment: You could also make use of .closest() and if you want you can also use the [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), .child(), .next() etc, to select elements relative to the element that was clicked.

Comment: Just an update to my previous comment, there is no child() selector, but rather a .children() selector and :nth-child() selector.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, `this` is essentially the context of the current function. In jQuery event callbacks,  `this` is set to be the source element of the event - not the selector string, which is what you are treating it as.

Instead, you want to do a test like: `if($("a", this).is(":contains(OK)")) {`

This works because the second parameter to the [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) is the context to search in, so you are only searching for the `a` tags under the source element of the click.

Answer (score 1):

Binding the click element to the Div, then checking the text string of the A tags will make both events happen on every click. You want to bind 2 separate click events on each A tag. Add an ID to each A tag, then try this code

```
$('#okLinkID').click(function(){
  console.log("OK!!");
});

$('#cancelLinkID').click(function(){
  console.log("Cancel!!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

//Attaches only one listener to the #message div and listens for any 'a' element within it to be clicked.

```
$('a','#message').on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        btnText = $this.text();
    console.log(btnText); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YA7Ds/